# Remove shadow from Toolbar when Navigation Drawer is Open - Material Design support library

Tags: android, material-design

I am implementing Material Design into my app that has a navigation drawer.  Amongst all the differing implementations of the Nav. Drawer and Toolbar with Material Design ([see this post](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/30/google-turns-design-inconsistency-ten-latest-round-navigation-drawers/)); I have chosen to keep the app feel similar to the ICS/Halo design and have the Nav Drawer slide out under the Toolbar.  The problem is that the Toolbar dims with the shadow like the rest of the activity when the nav drawer is open.  How would I keep the Toolbar from darkening?  If you see the image in the post I linked above I am after #6, 3 or 5, but my looks more like #9 now.

Example (from post above):

What I'm after (no shadow on Toolbar):

[image]

What I currently get (Toolbar darkens when nav drawer is open):

[image]

Here is the code for my main activity's XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.funkhaus.navdrawer.app.MainActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- We use a Toolbar so that our drawer can be displayed
         in front of the action bar; Added for Material Design -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</FrameLayout>

<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.funkhaus.brewwerks.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

The notable part being that the `<FrameLayout>` whose ID is `'container'` is where all my fragments are inflated, and its `marginTop` was set to the height of the Toolbar so its content would be below the Toolbar.  Similarly, the Navigation Drawer fragment also has its `marginTop` set to the height of the Toolbar so it slides out below it.

Comment: Put the Toolbar outside of the DrawerLayout.

Comment: From my understanding the `<DrawerLayout>` needs to be the root view when using the Navigation Drawer

Comment: The root of your content, yes. Not the root of your Toolbar.

Comment: Thanks @alanv, let me know if my posted answer seems reasonable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @alanv I fixed my issue.

My post above shows my `activity_main.xml` code; I simplified it to this, removing the Toolbar view and removing the `marginTop` formatting:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.funkhaus.navdrawer.app.MainActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.funkhaus.brewwerks.NavigationDrawerFragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I created a `toolbar.xml`, which I now setContentView() on in my main Activity that `<include>`'s the `activity_main.xml` above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- We use a Toolbar so that our drawer can be displayed
             in front of the action bar; Added for Material Design -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <include android:id="@+id/drawer_layout" layout="@layout/activity_main" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, in my Activity's `onCreate()` I `setContentView()` on the `toolbar.xml`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.toolbar);
    // Rest of code here....
```

Comment: The ActionBar is still supported, why not use it instead? It behaves exactly like that.

Comment: Even though we are all knowingly designing the Navigation Drawer against the updated Material Design guidelines, here is a link to the updated ones: http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 2):

```
You do it in the same xml like this, This is for underlying toolbar navigation like play store app design




  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.ccas.roadsideconnect.BaseFragmentActivity">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />



        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/img_actionbar_white_sm"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="58.0dip"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

The below code is for overlying toolbar navigation like Gmail APP design.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ccas.roadsideconnect.BaseFragmentActivity">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/img_actionbar_white_sm"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="58.0dip"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```